# Timezone conversion UTC->Europe/Berlin with day carryover

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

```
format(as.POSIXct("2022-06-05T23:00:00", "UTC"), tz ="Europe/Berlin")
>> [1] "2022-06-05 02:00:00"
```

This is daylight savings time, so I expected 2 hours difference, so the result should be on the next (!) day 1 am

```
"2022-06-06 01:00:00"
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The time was truncated. The result of `as.POSIXct("2022-06-05T23:00:00", "UTC")` is `"2022-06-05 UTC"`. Looks like `POSIXct` choked on `T` and just returned the date instead of throwing an error

Comment: `format(as.POSIXct("2022-06-05T23:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC"), tz = "Europe/Berlin")` fixes it and highlights the missed component, `format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"`. @PanagiotisKanavos, post as an answer?

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why did I get the result which was "moderately reasonable"? Please post as an answer.